# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'paymentInfo' of 'order' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

Im new to mern stack. I want to display single order details from list of orders. Single order details are fetch from database to redux dev tools. But those details are no show in browser and saying "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'paymentInfo' of 'order' as it is undefined." Any help is very much appreciated

```
//singleorder.js
import { useDispatch , useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getSingleOrder, clearErrors } from '../../../actions/orderActions'

import './UserSingleOrderCard.css'
  
const USOCard = ({ match }) => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const {loading, error, order } = useSelector(state => state.myOrderDetails)
      const {paymentInfo, deliveryInfo, orderStatus,userID,itemsPrice,user,totPrice,orderItems,createdAt,customerName} = order 


      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getSingleOrder(match.params.id));

        if(error){
          dispatch(clearErrors())
        }
      }, [dispatch,error,match.params.id])

      return (
        <Fragment>
        <div className="USOCCont211">
          <h1 className="orderIDtxt">Order Id</h1>
          <h2 className="orderID">{order._id}</h2>
          <div className="statsCont211">
            <div className="statusCard">
              <div className="statustxtdiv211">
                <p className="ststxt">Payment Status</p><br/>
                <p className={String(paymentInfo && paymentInfo.paymentStatus).includes('Paid') ? " statustxt211 green211" : "statustxt211 red211" }>{paymentInfo && paymentInfo.paymentStatus}</p><br/>
                <button className={String(paymentInfo && paymentInfo.paymentStatus).includes('Paid') ? "btn211 disabled" : "btn211" }>Pay</button>
              </div>
              <div className="stsimgcont211"><img className="stsimg211" src="./images/uovPayment.png" /></div>
            </div>
            <div className="statusCard">
              <div className="statustxtdiv211">
                <p className="ststxt">Order Status</p><br/>
                <p className={String(order.orderStatus).includes('Baked') ? " statustxt211 green211" : String(order.orderStatus).includes('Baking') ? " statustxt211 orange211" : "statustxt211 red211" }>{order.orderStatus}</p><br/>
              </div>
              <div className="stsimgcont211"><img className="stsimg211" src="./images/uovBaking.png" /></div>
            </div>
            <div className="statusCard">
              <div className="statustxtdiv211">
                <p className="ststxt">Delivery Status</p><br/>
                <p className={String(deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliverStatus).includes('Delivered') ? " statustxt211 green211" : String(deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliverStatus).includes('Delivering') ? " statustxt211 orange211" : "statustxt211 red211" }>{deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliverStatuss}</p><br/>
                <button className="btn211">Feedback</button>
              </div>
              <div className="stsimgcont211"><img className="stsimg211" src="./images/uovDeliver.png" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="DeliveryInfoUpdate211">
            <p className="oddivtxt211">Order Details</p>
            <center>
              <form>
                <table>
                  <tbody><tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Customer Name</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft213">{order.customerName}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Created At</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft213">{order.createdAt}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Telephone Number</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft212"><input className="form__field" type="text" placeholder={user && user.phone_no} /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Delivery Address</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft212"><input className="form__field" type="text" placeholder= {deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliveryAddress} /></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody></table><br /><br />
                <button className="btn212">Update Details</button>
              </form></center>
          </div>
          <div className="ordcaktxt211">
            <p>Ordered Cakies </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="tableContainer">
              <ul className="responsive-table">
                <li className="table-header">
                  <div className="col col-1">Product Name</div>
                  <div className="col col-2">Size</div>
                  <div className="col col-3">Topping</div>
                  <div className="col col-4">Qty</div>
                  <div className="col col-5">Price</div>
                </li>

                {orderItems && orderItems.map(item => (
                <li className="table-row">
                  <div className="col col-1" data-label="Product Name">{item.product_name}</div>
                  <div className="col col-2" data-label="Size">{item.size}</div>
                  <div className="col col-3" data-label="Topping ">{item.topping}</div>
                  <div className="col col-4" data-label="Qty">{item.qty}</div>
                  <div className="col col-5" data-label="Price">{item.itemsPrice}</div>
                </li>
                 ))}

              </ul>
              <center> <div className="totAmnt211">Total Amount: {order.totPrice}</div> </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="footer211">
            <button className="btnfoot213">Back to Orders</button>
            <button className="btnfoot214">Delete Order</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        </Fragment>
  )
}
          
export default USOCard
```

```
//action.js
//User get single order details
export const getSingleOrder = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try{
        dispatch ({ type:ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST });
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/order/${id}`)
        dispatch({
            type:ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload:data.order
            
        })
    } catch(error) {
        dispatch({
            type:ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is that you are not handling the loading of the data. The variable order will be undefined until the data has been fetched, and it throws you that error because you are trying to destructure some properties from undefined. There's a bunch of different things you can do. I suggest you add something like this...

```
const USOCard = ({ match }) => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const {loading, error, order } = useSelector(state => state.myOrderDetails)


      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getSingleOrder(match.params.id));

        if(error){
          dispatch(clearErrors())
        }
      }, [dispatch,error,match.params.id])

      if (!order) {
          return null
      }

      const {paymentInfo, deliveryInfo, orderStatus,userID,itemsPrice,user,totPrice,orderItems,createdAt,customerName} = order 

      return (
        <Fragment>
        <div className="USOCCont211">
          <h1 className="orderIDtxt">Or......
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because you are trying to access an `order` that isn't fetched yet, you have to check if data is fetched by checking if `loading` prop is false:

**Problem**

```
const {loading, error, order } = useSelector(state => state.myOrderDetails)  // <=== At this moment the data isn't fetched yet so the order is null
```

**Solution**

```
    let paymentInfo,
        deliveryInfo,
        orderStatus,
        userID,
        itemsPrice,
        user,
        totPrice,
        orderItems,
        createdAt,
        customerName;
    
      if (!loading) {
        paymentInfo = order.paymentInfo;
        deliveryInfo = order.deliveryInfo;
        orderStatus = order.orderStatus;
        userID = order.userID;
        itemsPrice = order.itemsPrice;
        user = order.user;
        totPrice = order.totPrice;
        orderItems = order.orderItems;
        createdAt = order.createdAt;
        customerName = order.customerName;
      }
```

You component

```
//singleorder.js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getSingleOrder, clearErrors } from '../../../actions/orderActions';

import './UserSingleOrderCard.css';

const USOCard = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading, error, order } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.myOrderDetails
  );
  let paymentInfo,
    deliveryInfo,
    orderStatus,
    userID,
    itemsPrice,
    user,
    totPrice,
    orderItems,
    createdAt,
    customerName;

  if (!loading) {
    paymentInfo = order.paymentInfo;
    deliveryInfo = order.deliveryInfo;
    orderStatus = order.orderStatus;
    userID = order.userID;
    itemsPrice = order.itemsPrice;
    user = order.user;
    totPrice = order.totPrice;
    orderItems = order.orderItems;
    createdAt = order.createdAt;
    customerName = order.customerName;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSingleOrder(match.params.id));

    if (error) {
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, match.params.id]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="USOCCont211">
          <h1 className="orderIDtxt">Order Id</h1>
          <h2 className="orderID">{order._id}</h2>
          <div className="statsCont211">
            <div className="statusCard">
              <div className="statustxtdiv211">
                <p className="ststxt">Payment Status</p>
                <br />
                <p
                  className={
                    String(paymentInfo && paymentInfo.paymentStatus).includes(
                      'Paid'
                    )
                      ? ' statustxt211 green211'
                      : 'statustxt211 red211'
                  }
                >
                  {paymentInfo && paymentInfo.paymentStatus}
                </p>
                <br />
                <button
                  className={
                    String(paymentInfo && paymentInfo.paymentStatus).includes(
                      'Paid'
                    )
                      ? 'btn211 disabled'
                      : 'btn211'
                  }
                >
                  Pay
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="stsimgcont211">
                <img className="stsimg211" src="./images/uovPayment.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="statusCard">
              <div className="statustxtdiv211">
                <p className="ststxt">Order Status</p>
                <br />
                <p
                  className={
                    String(order.orderStatus).includes('Baked')
                      ? ' statustxt211 green211'
                      : String(order.orderStatus).includes('Baking')
                      ? ' statustxt211 orange211'
                      : 'statustxt211 red211'
                  }
                >
                  {order.orderStatus}
                </p>
                <br />
              </div>
              <div className="stsimgcont211">
                <img className="stsimg211" src="./images/uovBaking.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="statusCard">
              <div className="statustxtdiv211">
                <p className="ststxt">Delivery Status</p>
                <br />
                <p
                  className={
                    String(deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliverStatus).includes(
                      'Delivered'
                    )
                      ? ' statustxt211 green211'
                      : String(
                          deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliverStatus
                        ).includes('Delivering')
                      ? ' statustxt211 orange211'
                      : 'statustxt211 red211'
                  }
                >
                  {deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliverStatuss}
                </p>
                <br />
                <button className="btn211">Feedback</button>
              </div>
              <div className="stsimgcont211">
                <img className="stsimg211" src="./images/uovDeliver.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="DeliveryInfoUpdate211">
            <p className="oddivtxt211">Order Details</p>
            <center>
              <form>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Customer Name</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft213">{order.customerName}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Created At</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft213">{order.createdAt}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Telephone Number</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft212">
                        <input
                          className="form__field"
                          type="text"
                          placeholder={user && user.phone_no}
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="tbleleft211">Delivery Address</td>
                      <td className="tbleleft212">
                        <input
                          className="form__field"
                          type="text"
                          placeholder={
                            deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliveryAddress
                          }
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <br />
                <br />
                <button className="btn212">Update Details</button>
              </form>
            </center>
          </div>
          <div className="ordcaktxt211">
            <p>Ordered Cakies </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="tableContainer">
              <ul className="responsive-table">
                <li className="table-header">
                  <div className="col col-1">Product Name</div>
                  <div className="col col-2">Size</div>
                  <div className="col col-3">Topping</div>
                  <div className="col col-4">Qty</div>
                  <div className="col col-5">Price</div>
                </li>

                {orderItems &&
                  orderItems.map((item) => (
                    <li className="table-row">
                      <div className="col col-1" data-label="Product Name">
                        {item.product_name}
                      </div>
                      <div className="col col-2" data-label="Size">
                        {item.size}
                      </div>
                      <div className="col col-3" data-label="Topping ">
                        {item.topping}
                      </div>
                      <div className="col col-4" data-label="Qty">
                        {item.qty}
                      </div>
                      <div className="col col-5" data-label="Price">
                        {item.itemsPrice}
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  ))}
              </ul>
              <center>
                {' '}
                <div className="totAmnt211">
                  Total Amount: {order.totPrice}
                </div>{' '}
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="footer211">
            <button className="btnfoot213">Back to Orders</button>
            <button className="btnfoot214">Delete Order</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <br />
      <br />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default USOCard;
```

Comment: This one also worked for me